# RCTfont+FA5.h file not found for react-native-vector-icons

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-vector-icons

**For react-native-vector-icons RCTfont+FA5.h** file not found, I don't know where exactly have i gone wrong?

steps I did:

1.npm i react-native-vector-icons

2.react-native link react-native-vector-icons

and when trying to build i keep getting the error 'RCTfont+FA5.h' not found.

P.S: I am using cocoapods , i have made sure i have ran pod install inside ios folder and also using .xcworkspace file for building.

Thanks for taking time reading it and trying helping out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use link in RN, you should use `npm i react-native-vector-icons --save` or `npm i react-native-vector-icons --save-dev`.

From  [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios)

"Note: --save or --save-dev flag is very important for this step. React Native will link your libs based on dependencies and devDependencies in your package.json file."

So to fix it, unlink and remove the package..

`react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons` && `npm remove react-native-vector-icons`

Then reinstall using --save or --save-dev and link again.

Comment: Oh ! thanks i completely missed the exact step i.e not using --save. Soo , Now having said I have already install react-native-vector-icons, what is the solution @stever ?

Comment: Edited the answer with steps to remove and unlink before trying again.

Comment: Nice!  Gotta love those easy solutions to obtuse Xcode errors!

Answer (score 3):

`--save` didn't help in my case. Upgrading to `"react-native-vector-icons": "6.4.1"` solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

I had to downgrade to "react-native-vector-icons":"6.3.0".

This version has 'RCTFont+FA5.h' in 'node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager' (as opposed to "6.4.1").

Then I removed the entry from the pod file and added the project manually in Xcode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that file `RCTfont+FA5.m` is not present in `node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager` with version 6.4.0 onwards

I tried with version 6.3.0, dd'nt work

Downgraded to 6.10 and its working